# NOOBS shows black screen unless I switch to to another video setting and then back to HDMI

Tags: raspbian, video, config.txt, noobs

When I first boot my Raspberry Pi into NOOBS, I get a blank screen until I push keys 3 or 4 and then select 1, switching it to HDMI again. Then, it works fine and I can install Raspbian, but after I install it and boot, I just get a black screen. The monitor is active (backlight on) but nothing on the screen. What do I need to do for video to work?

EDIT - Pidora works fine after install, no settings needed. No idea why Raspbian won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had what is probably the same problem. I was never able to get any HDMI output on Raspbian if I installed it from NOOBS. Eventually I gave up on NOOBS and just made an SD card with Raspbian on it. That worked just fine.
I used the Raspbian instructions on http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads

Comment: I actually ended up fixing it - I jammed down a bunch of keys when booting to Raspbian and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem.  I knew Raspbian was loading ok because I could log in via SSH.  I am using an HDMI to VGA adapter to the monitor.  Raspbian failed but Pidora would work fine.  For me the secret sauce was boosting the HDMI output by setting config_hdmi_boost=4 in my config.txt file.  I think that Pidora must set a higher default output current than Raspbian.  Once I set that, safe mode started working and it continued to work fine after switching to full resolution.